# Get rich value from Angular intl-tel-input custom directive attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have developed custom directive for using intltelinput jquery plugin. I want to get rich value that contains suc as country and  dial code of selected number  as following like;

```
scope.nationalphoneinfo.number = elem.intlTelInput("getNumber");
scope.nationalphoneinfo.country = elem.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData");
scope.nationalphoneinfo.isValid = true;
```

But I can't see nationalphoneinfo data  in controller. How  does this get nationalphoneinfo in controller.

The direcitive definition:

```
var intlTepInputDirecitive = pluginDirecitvesModule.directive('intltelinput', function () {
        return {
            require: "^ngModel",
            restrict: "A",
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                ngModel: "=",
                nationalphoneinfo :"=nationalphoneinfo"

            },
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

                elem.intlTelInput({defaultCountry: scope.defaultCountry,
                    preferredCountries: ["tr", "de", "nl", "us", "fr", "en"],
                    utilsScript: ASSETS_PATH + "app/bower_components/utils.js"});
                elem.bind("blur", function () {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        if (elem.intlTelInput("isValidNumber{")) {

                            scope.nationalphoneinfo.number = elem.intlTelInput("getNumber");
                            scope.nationalphoneinfo.country = elem.intlTelInput("getSelectedCountryData");
                            scope.nationalphoneinfo.isValid = true;
                        } else {
                            scope.nationalphoneinfo.isValid = false;
                        }

                    });
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

The directive declaration in html:

```
<input  intltelinput type="tel" id="phone" name="mobilePhone" ng-required="true" class="form-control pl tel"  ng-model="mobilePhone" nationalphoneinfo="nationalPhoneInfo">
```